# Externalize pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, shell-escape

To speed up processing of `pgfplots`, it should be possible, as I understand, to write

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
```

However, I get an error (Mactex 2016) that seems to have something to do with system calls, `\write18`, and the like. I get

> ```
> ! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'lualatex -halt-on-error -interact
> ion=batchmode -jobname "portoptreport1-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{porto
> ptreport1}\input{portoptreport1}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'port
> optreport1-figure0' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that
>  you have enabled system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'.
>  Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the com
> mand simply failed? Error messages can be found in 'portoptreport1-figure0.log'
> . If you continue now, I'll try to typeset the picture.
> ```

Comment: [Welcome to tex.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/49901) Does running `lualatex --shell-escape filename.tex` from a terminal (in the folder of filename.tex) work? (Or possibly `lualatex --enable-write18 filename.tex`)

Comment: Thanks!The option --shell-escape (or --enable-write18) is enough to get it to work with pdflatex. Herb Schultz, on the TeX on Mac OS X Mailing List, told me the missing bit. In the case of Lualatex, it works if adding following snippet before \begin{document}:

\ifx\directlua\@undefined
\else
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\RequirePackage{shellesc}
\fi

Comment: I see! More than I knew. You can answer your own question to provide an answer for any future users that come here with the same problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments.